# foreach by Outlook stores is throwing exception

Tags: c#, outlook

I get the exception during foreach by Outlook stores

> Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0xBBC7007E
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()

here example code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appl = _oApp as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
List<string> storeIDs = new List<string>();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store s in appl.Session.Stores)
{
    storeIDs.Add(s.StoreID);
}
```

Could anybody give me any suggestions what cause of the issue?

**Update:**
That is addin for outlook.

I rewrote to using `for` like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appl = _oApp as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
List<string> names = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= appl.Session.Stores.Count; i++)
{
    names.Add(appl.Session.Stores[i].DisplayName);
}
```

I get this exception

> Error Message:
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> MAPI was unable to load the information service IrisMS.DLL. Be sure the service is correctly installed and configured.
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Stores.get_Item(Object Index)

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Console?  Winforms?  WPF?

Comment: What are the stores you have the in the profile?

Comment: Is there something in the IRIS store that you need? Or can you just skip that one?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko When I tried to use Redemption I got it: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: 0x8007007E ulVersion: 0 Error: An unexpected error has occurred. MAPI was unable to load the information service IrisMS.DLL. Be sure the service is correctly installed and configured. Component: MAPI 1 ulLowLevelError: 0 ulContext: 1026 at ORedemption.IRDOStore.get_Name()

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a BCM store, and the store provider is not installed.